# calcite, id filters , what is the easiest way to get them?

Tags: apache-calcite

I would like to find the easiest way to get the filters for id columns of my tables. Currently I use FilterableTable but that returns the filters as an expression tree and I would have to scan for it. I am wondering if there is an easier way to get the filter of my PK columns (the one I declare as keys or as indexed), i.e. get a from-to kind of structure.

EDIT: so what ideally I would expect is to extract a list of id ranges for the query, i.e. from filters to [id1 ... id2] , [id3...id4] and so on, where id1

Comment: can you expand a bit,  if you are doing parsing level work, guess that's what you have to do, iterate over the filtered columns

Comment: @zinking I've edited the question to include an example. I believe there shouldn't be any helper code that can do that for me and I would need to write the code myself.